# Sensors to switch on LED

Tags: python, sensor

Hi this is my first post on here. I am attempting to switch on a LED by the temperature differential between two ds18b20 sensors.  The sensors print out the degrees C but I cannot get them to switch on the LED.  Any help with the code would be much appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
import glob
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
#LED1 connected to pin 13
LED1 = 13
pinList =[LED1]

os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

def read_temp_raw(i):
    base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
    device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28*')[i]
    device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'
    f = open(device_file, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return lines

def read_temp(i):
    lines = read_temp_raw(i)
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines = read_temp_raw()
    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
    if equals_pos != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
        temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
    return temp_c

while True:
    print(read_temp(0))
    print(read_temp(1))
#    print(read_temp(2))
#    print(read_temp(3))
    time.sleep(3)

if (temp[0]>(temp[1]+2)):
            GPIO.output(LED1,GPIO.HIGH)
if (temp[0]<(temp[1]+2)):
            GPIO.output(LED1,GPIO.LOW)

else :
            GPIO.output(LED1,GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.cleanup
```

Comment: You may want to take a moment to read about properly formatting source code in your questions. That will make it much easier for people to read.

Comment: Where is assigned the value of temp[0] and temp[1]?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are not assigning your array values. Change your read_temp method to use the index you give it.

```
def read_temp(i):
    lines = read_temp_raw(i)
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines = read_temp_raw()
    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
    if equals_pos != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
        temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
    temp[i] = temp_c # <-- this seems missing
    return temp_c
```

There are other logical problems as well. My Python isn't great but it looks to me like the IF statements that control the LED pin are unreachable due to the WHILE TRUE loop. Maybe they should be indented too?

```
while True:
    print(read_temp(0))
    print(read_temp(1))
#    print(read_temp(2))
#    print(read_temp(3))
    time.sleep(3)

    if (temp[0]>(temp[1]+2)):
        GPIO.output(LED1,GPIO.HIGH)
    if (temp[0]<(temp[1]+2)):
        GPIO.output(LED1,GPIO.LOW)
    else :
        GPIO.output(LED1,GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.cleanup
```

I may be wrong there, it could just be formatting on the question (your if's CONTENTS required no indentation).